# Implement Java client for WCF .NET soap server using wsHttpBinding

Tags: java, .net

I'm trying to implement a java client that interfaces with a .NET server talking soap v1.2. More specifically, the server is using wsHttpBinding (not the 'BasicHttpBinding' variant) and requires fetching of a token via a request with a 'RequestSecurityToken' body. I should also point out that I have no control over this server :(

I can generate java code using 
wsimport -d ./ -extension -keep -p client https://path/to/wsdl

But I have little joy - the wsimport prints a few warnings - 
 SOAP port "WSHttpBinding_Feed": uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding

Can this be done?

Comment: When you say Java you mean Oracle Java or js?

Comment: I think what could be always useful is to generate/ask for sample (working) request-response pairs. After that you will see that the generated client what extent be able to create acceptable requests and you will see what is missing/what are assembled incorrectly.